# Join the list in a variable

Tags: tcl

I have a list in one file called a_list as

```
top_a
.
.
.
top_e
```

Now I would like to append list into variable data which is read the a_list, just like:

```
set data [read $RTL]
puts "flag1:$data"
```

& output is something like this:

```
flag1:top_a
top_b
top_c
top_d
top_e
```

Now I am trying to insert into data through another variable which contains list, for example variable is:

```
set fr "top_f top_g"
```

I want output of data as

```
top_a
top_b
top_c
top_c
top_d
top_e
top_f
top_g
```

What should be the correct approach to do so,as I have tried for lappend or join but I am getting something like,

```
top_a top_b ... top_e {top_f top_f}
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Edit: I am able to narrow is down with foreach as

```
foreach list $fr{
set a $list
}
```

I have something like:

```
top_f
top_g
```

How should i append variable 'a' into variable 'data' as:

```
top_a
top_b
top_c
top_c
top_d
top_e
top_f
top_g
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lappend data {*}$fr
```

if you have Tcl 8.5+, or

```
eval lappend data $fr
```

if you have 8.4 or older (unsupported, so upgrade in that case).

Documentation:
[eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Could also do `foreach value $fr {lappend data $value}`… but using `lappend` as in this answer is clearer.